# Show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated

Tags: correlation

The question I'm given is: Suppose that $X$ has the uniform distribution on the interval $[-2,2]$ and $Y=X^6$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Also are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I know that $f_x(x)=1/4$, $E(X)=2$, $Var(X)=4/3$ and that $X=Y^(1/6)$.

What do I do from here? I'm thrown by the fact that $Y(-2)=64$ and $Y(2)=64$. Does this mean that Y is in $[0, 64]$?

Comment: None of these is necessary, simply note that the distribution of $X$ is symmetric hence $$E(X^7)=E(X)=0$$ which implies that $$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(X^7)-E(X)E(X^6)=0$$ which implies that $$\mathrm{Corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(X)\mathrm{var}(Y)}}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Two r.v.'s $X,Y$ are uncorrelated if their covariance $COV (X,Y) = 0$.

Recall that $COV (XY) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$. Moreover, when $X$ is uniform on $[-2,2]$ (and thus symmetric around $0$, then $E(X^k) = 0$ when $k$ is an odd integer.

Now you are ready to compute
$$COV (XY) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(X \cdot X^6) - E(X)E(X^6) = E(X^7)- E(X)E(X^6) =0$$
because $E(X)=E(X^7) = 0$.

[ADDED AFTER YOUR REQUEST in comments]

Two r.v.'s $X,Y$ are independent if $P(A_X \cap B_Y) = P(A_X) P(B_Y)$ for any event $A_X$ concerning $X$ and any event $B_Y$ concerning $Y$.

Let $A_X = \{ X \ge 1 \}$ and $B_Y = \{ Y \ge 1 \}$. Then 
$$P(A_X \cap B_Y) = P (X \ge 1, Y \ge 1) = P (X \ge 1) = \frac{1}{4}$$
but
$$P(A_X) P (B_Y) = P (X \ge 1) P(Y \ge 1) = \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$$
Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: How do I tell if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Independence is not needed. The COV formula is true for arbitrary r.v.'s.

Comment: By the way, if you knew that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you would also know that they uncorrelated. Independence implies uncorrelatedness (but not vice versa).

Comment: How would I prove if $X$ and $Y$ are correlated or not?

Comment: Read first line of my answer.

Comment: Oh oops sorry I meant: How would I prove if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: I have added this to my answer.

Comment: If X and Y are independent so are X^6 and Y which is not the case here!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so essentially, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent because to find $Y$ you need to know $X$?

Answer (score 1):

$E(X) = \int_{-2}^2 x f_x(x)\, dx = 0$ and $E(Y) = E(X^6) = \int_{-2}^{2} x^6 f_x(x)\, dx = 64/7$. Thus
\begin{align*}
Cov(X,Y) &= E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))\\
&= E(X(X^6-\frac{64}{7})) \\
&= E(X^7 - \frac{64}{7}X)\\
&= \int_{-2}^2 \left(x^7 - \frac{64}{7}x\right)f_x(x) \, dx \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get $E(Y)=64/7$?

Comment: $\int_{-2}^2 x^6 f_x(x) dx = \frac{1}{4}\left. \frac{x^7}{7} \right|_{-2}^2 = \frac{256}{28} = \frac{64}{7}$